# 'webview' is not a known element in electron angular app

Tags: javascript, angular, webview, electron

i'm creating a desktop app using electron. We have a requirement of loading webpages and interacting with the web pages.

We came to know what [electron has  tag for](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/webview-tag.md) that

as per the documentations, this is our **main.js** file configuration

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      webviewTag: true <--------------- as said by the documentation
    }
  })
```

now is our **webpage.component.html** file we have added this tag

```
<webview src="https://www.github.com/"></webview>
```

this is our **web-page.component.ts** file

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'webpage',
  templateUrl: './webpage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./webpage.component.scss']
})
export class WebpageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

but we are getting this error again and again, we don't know what we are doing wrong!

> ```
> ERROR in src/app/webpage/webpage.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'webview' is not a known element:
> 1. If 'webview' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
> 2. To allow any element add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component.
>
> 1 <webview src="https://www.github.com/"></webview>
>   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
>   src/app/webpage/webpage.component.ts:5:16
>     5   templateUrl: './webpage.component.html',
>                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>     Error occurs in the template of component WebpageComponent.
> ```

would like to know what we are doing wrong!